# Applying bootstrap classes prevents DropDownList from opening

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have this page that I recently used Bootstrap to make it responsive.  Prior to the responsiveness the page worked correctly but looked bad in different screen sizes.  Now, it looks great in multiple screen sizes but the dropdownlists do not work. If I remove the class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-xs-12"then the dropdownlist works again.  Also, if I pull the dropdownlist out of the div and put it somewhere else on the page it also works.

For clarification when I say it doesn't work I mean if I click on the dropdownlist it does not expand.  btw, I have more dropdownlists in the form, I just removed them to be more concise in the code.

Here is the code:

```
<div row>
     <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-xs-12">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                 <tr>
                       <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                       <td>
                             <span style="font-weight:normal;">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Category, "CategoryId", "CategoryName"))</span>
                             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                       </td>
                 </tr>       
           </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found that I can add this link below to the page which will fix the dropdown but it messes up all the formatting.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and here is the rendered HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-xs-12">
     <table class="table table-condensed">
          <tr>
              <th><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="CategoryId">Category</label></th>                    
          </tr>
               <td>
                    <span style="font-weight:normal;"><select data-val="true" data-val-required="The Category field is required." id="CategoryId" name="CategoryId"><option value="ae159a72-2447-42b6-9693-149964fdc896">Other</option>
                         <option value="45cf430d-bd7e-4003-ab97-33fb55520551">E-Mail/ Outlook</option>
                         <option value="dc27d6b2-59d9-46fd-b92e-42cf70b7f732">Administrative</option>
                         <option value="44124582-e37a-47f4-a98a-5f97049ba5b9">OPS</option>
                         <option selected="selected" value="c0ed4cd4-400f-479c-aa26-8522667241d5">Automation</option>
                         <option value="9080fef6-382f-49ad-993b-9f0689f90c95">Network</option>
                         <option value="d7b2ce5f-f9e6-48f1-a6bb-b4141c8bdc7e">stcusa.com</option>
                         <option value="d8121018-a401-48a0-9dec-c209b3be3495">Software</option>
                         <option value="7ba3a1e6-5cd6-4d63-8c09-d54826261441">Reporting</option>
                         <option value="efe7c637-e210-44d4-83a3-dac3199f5cae">Phones</option>
                         <option value="f8f35cdd-09a6-459d-9a7c-dd28df0f8776">Hardware</option>
    </select></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct your div tag:

```
<div row>
```

should be

```
<div class="row">
```

In most of situations where an element does not respond to clicks! there's another div covering your it because of problems in container and row DIVs. It's not about razor, look into your rendered html.

Comment: KavehG, Thank you for your answer.  I changed that and it still doesn't work.  Like I said in my original post if I remove class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-xs-12" from the div then it does work.  or if I add that link but in either case they mess up the formatting on the page (in different ways).

Comment: Could you  post your rendered html please!

Comment: KavehG, I added a snipped of the rendered HTML for the problem area.

Comment: I tried your code and it works in a page I was working on just now, there's nothing wrong with the drop down nor with column. There must be something in the outer divs! Inspect other elements in the page for example in chrome developer tools, select all other elements one by one, see if they are covering your drop down list!?

Comment: KavehG, just curious why would removing the class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-xs-12" make it work again then?  I will test what you are saying now just curious why that fixes it.

Comment: It changes your div's position from static to relative and the float style can take your div out of the document flow. But without seeing your whole markup, it's just a guess!